# how to get page html in httpmodule?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to replace commented html token with text in httpmodule endrequest.
How to get the page html in httpmodule?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`HttpResponse.Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx) for this:

> This property gets or sets a wrapping
>   filter object that is used to modify
>   the HTTP entity body before
>   transmission.

Here are several articles which could help you with this:

1. [Modifying the HTTP Response Using
   Filters](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx)
2. [Producing XHTML-Compilant Pages With Response Filters](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters)
3. [Removing White Chars from ASP.NET Output using Response.Filter property](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RemovingWhiteSpacesAspNet.aspx)

Comment: Can i use HttpResponse.Filter in Application_EndRequest() Event?

Comment: @balu, why you specifically want to use Application_EndRequest? Please read about Response Filters - the way that they work, you need to apply them on/before `PostReleaseRequestState` event.